# Weird behaviour of dijit.Menu upon creation of a grid in IE 8/7

Tags: menu, dojo

I have a simple page with a BorderContainer. The top region is a simple ContentPange, and the center region is a TabContainer. On the top region there is a button that creates a dijit.Menu and binds it to the top region. There is also another button that creates a EnhancedGrid and adds it to the TabContainer. The issue is a follows:

Scenario 1) If you create the menu, and then do a right-click, the menu will show correctly, as long as the grid is not created before the menu is shown for the first time.

Scenario 2) Any other option (create the menu, the grid, and then do the right-click, or create the grid, the menu and then do the right-click) will provoke a blink in the page, (like the page is resizing). A scroll bar will be shown for a second on the right side of the body, and the menu will appear for a second, and then disappear. If you click again, the menu will appear, but opening a sub menu will close will close the main menu, and the options in the sub menu will not work.

I've been able to create a small test case. The behavior is reproducible with any version of dojo previous to 1.8. I've also seen that the menu works just fine if the Border Container has an height diferent than 100% (the width does not affect)

I believe the issue is related to that blink. It seems like the moment the menu is shown the layout is resizing, and in that moment the menu lost the focus and closes itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dojo/dojo.js' djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, locale: 'en-us'"></script>

<script>
 dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.NestedSorting");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Menu");
dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.ContentPane");
</script>    

<style type='text/css'>
@import url('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/tundra/EnhancedGrid.css');
@import url('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css');
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    html, body { overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
</style>

<script>
    function createMenu(){
        var sMenu = new dijit.Menu({});
        var pSubMenu = new dijit.Menu();
        // Para enviar por mail
        pSubMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
            label: "email 1",
            onClick: function(e){
                alert(1)
            }
        }));

        pSubMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
            label: "email 2",
            onClick: function(e){
                alert(2)
            }
        }));

        // Añadimos el submenu a la entrada de SendTo
        sMenu.addChild(new dijit.PopupMenuItem({
            label: "SendTo",
            popup: pSubMenu
        }));

    sMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
        label: "Open"
    }))
    sMenu.startup();
    return sMenu;
}
</script>
   </head>
 <body class="tundra eco">

  <div id="BorderContainerLevel1" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: none; border:none; padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;">
   <div id="pane-test-1" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="height: 105px; "><!-- z-index:10-->
    La cabecera
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" onclick='launch()'>Create grid</button>
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" onclick='launchMenu()'>Create Menu</button>
   </div>
    <script>

function launch(){
    var layout = [[
        {
        name: '&nbsp;',
        hidden: true,
        field: 'idDocument'},
    {
        name: '&nbsp;',
        field: 'contentType',
        width: '8%'},
    {
        name: "Name",
        field: 'name',
        width: '62%'},
    {
        name: "Date",
        field: 'date',
        width: '20%'},
    {
        name: "Size",
        field: 'size',
        width: '10%'}
    ]];
    var i = 0;

    var gridId = "grid_" + i

    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: gridId,
        query: {
            idDocument: '*'
        },
        title:"titulo",
        structure: layout
    })
    bankerTabContainer.addChild(grid)
    grid.startup();


    var myJson = {"identifier":"idDocument","items":[{"contentType":"pdf","date":"2011-10-26T16:10:45","documentType":"USERDOCUMENT","documentTypeDescription":"User Document","idDocument":534044,"idUser":"OFFMARA","name":"test II Modules.pdf","size":15704}]}
        grid.setStore(new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                data: myJson
            }));

}
  </script>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="bankerTabContainer" jsId="bankerTabContainer" style="height: 100%;width: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px;" region="center"></div>



  </div>

<script>
function launchMenu(){
    dijit.byId('BorderContainerLevel1').resize();
    var menu1 = createMenu();
    menu1.bindDomNode(dojo.byId("pane-test-1"));
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was unable to create a test case in jsfiddle(I believe due to jsfiddle using an iframe, so I uploaded the source to github https://github.com/jlmagc/test/blob/master/test-menu-issue.html.

Comment: and you should be able to see the page using the following link:
http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://raw.github.com/jlmagc/test/master/test-menu-issue.html

Comment: so why dont you keep the height under 100 % for the ie 7 & 8 ?

Comment: Well, I need the BorderContainer to adapt to the user's screen resolution.

Comment: doesnt 99 % also adapt to the screen resolution ?

Comment: Humm. That's an interesting thing. I checked and it works with 94%, but if I make the menu any longer (by adding a third option) then it does not work anymore, I need to take the height to 92%. It seems like the layout is somehow using space below the bordercontainer to create the menu, and then reposition it on the mouse's position, and that is causing the resizing of the screen.

Comment: Interesting, maybe you could do a overflow hidden on the menu thing, so that no height is consumed...

Comment: I looked into it using IE8 but couldnt solve it, sorry